# Mongodb function TypeError

Tags: mongodb, shell

In the mongo shell, running the following line works fine:

```
director =  = 'George Lucas'
db.movie.find( { director: director} ).sort( { title: 1 })
```

I created the following function inside the mongo shell as a test:

```
function bydirector(db, director) {
  db.movie.findOne( { director: director} ).sort( { title: 1 });
}
```

Running the function with "bydirector(director)" returns the following error:

2015-11-22T19:24:26.713-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: db.movie is undefined :
bydirector@(shell):1:39
@(shell):1:1

Any idea why it is failing?  I am passing a variable named director with the search key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

First you are reassigning the global value `db` with `director` in your function parameters. Make sure you run the function with

```
bydirector(db, director)
```

Also, your two queries are not the same. You cannot call `sort` on the result of a `findOne` query which is an object. But that will only rear its head after you fix the first issue.

Comment: Thank you for catching that, I have altered the function from findOne to find; the error have gone away, but I am not receiving any result with the call you have recommended.  While on the subject, is there a way to echo the expanded line in the function?

Comment: you need to return the result set from the function if you want it to print it out. `return db.movie.find(...)`

Answer (score 0):

According to above mentioned description as an alternative solution to error occurring while execution of above code snippet,please note that function bydirector accepts two arguments

(a) Mongo database object

(b) Filter value according to which document needs to be filtered in mongodb collection.

Please try executing following code snippet

In below mentioned code snippet please note the return statement to  return result of query execution to calling function

```
var director='George Lucas';
function bydirector(db, director) {
 result=db.movie.findOne( { director: director} ).sort( { title: 1 });
 return result;
}
result=bydirector(db,director)
```